# Gravitational waves (linearized gravity)

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory

Even in the Schwarzschild metric we can write $g_{uv}=\eta_{uv}+h_{uv}$ where $h_{uv}$ is very small. So after some coordinate transformation (using gauge freedom) we can simplify the Einstein equation to   $◻h_{uv}=0$. So here $h_{uv}$ perform wave motion in that coordinate. But the Schwarzschild solution is static and stationary. So it should not emit any GR Waves, I suppose. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

In the linearized approximation, the Schwarzschild metric only has the nontrivial component $h_{00}$ and it behaves as
$$ h_{00} = \frac{-2GM}{r} $$
This function obeys the wave equation. Well, the second time derivative contributes zero so what matters is that the Laplacian of $1/r$ equals zero – for the same reason as in electrostatics etc.

More precisely, it is proportional to a multiple the three-dimensional delta-function which doesn't vanish at the origin. But that's where the linearization breaks down anyway, and we have a singularity there etc. and a special discussion is needed there. But whenever the linearization holds, the linearized wave equation is satisfied. But as we saw, it doesn't mean that every nontrivial solution has to have moving waves.

It would be true if we demanded the Laplacian to be zero everywhere and the $h$ to vanish at infinity etc. In that case, $h$ could be Fourier transformed and the waves would be there. But the 3D Fourier transform of $1/r$ is $C/p^2$ which is a wave packet mostly sitting near $p=0$ which is why the solution is static.